# How can i get different new products store wise?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, blocks, new-products

I am getting same new products in my all store, i am using TATVA SOFT Catalog Extensions Configuration.

```
{{block type="catalogextensions/newproduct_home_list" name="newproduct_list" category_id="2276" template="catalogextensions/home_newproduct.phtml"}}
```

And this is my block code which i added in static block for assign different store, even i have added `category_id="2276"` for different store different id. But displaying same products in all store.

Please guide me how can i solve this ! [Here](http://naijashop.com.ng/) is the site link.

```
<?php



/*

 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates

 * and open the template in the editor.

 */



/**

 * Description of List

 *

 * @author om

 */

class Tatva_Catalogextensions_Block_Newproduct_Home_List extends Tatva_Catalogextensions_Block_Newproduct_List

{



    protected function _getProductCollection()

    {

        parent::__construct();

        $storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();

        $todayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);


        $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()

            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')

            ->addStoreFilter($storeId, false)

            ->addAttributeToSort("entity_id","DESC")

            ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image'))

            ->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInSiteIds())

            ->setOrder($this->get_order(), $this->get_order_dir());

        if(Mage::getStoreConfig('catalogextensions/config4/max_product'))

        {

            $products->setPageSize(Mage::getStoreConfig('catalogextensions/config4/max_product'));

        }





        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);

        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);

        Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($products);



        $this->_productCollection = $products;



        return $this->_productCollection;

    }



    function get_prod_count()

    {

        //unset any saved limits

        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->unsLimitPage();

        return (isset($_REQUEST['limit'])) ? intval($_REQUEST['limit']) : 9;

    }// get_prod_count



    function get_cur_page()

    {

        return (isset($_REQUEST['p'])) ? intval($_REQUEST['p']) : 1;

    }// get_cur_page



    function get_order()

    {

        return (isset($_REQUEST['order'])) ? ($_REQUEST['order']) : 'position';

    }// get_order



    function get_order_dir()

    {

        return (isset($_REQUEST['dir'])) ? ($_REQUEST['dir']) : 'desc';

    }// get_direction



        public function getToolbarHtml()

        {



        }

}
```

Comment: can you post  newproduct_home_list this List.php block file code here?

Comment: @AkhileshPatel i have updated my question !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you post the wrong block file here as per your block

```
{{block type="catalogextensions/newproduct_home_list" name="newproduct_list" category_id="2276" template="catalogextensions/home_newproduct.phtml"}}
```

File path should be `app/code/local/Tatva/Catalogextensions/Block/Newproduct/Home/List.php` and class should be called `Tatva_Catalogextensions_Block_Newproduct_Home_List` which I find in your extension.

In this file in function `_getProductCollection` I didn't see any filter by the category id. you might be need to add category filter in collection so your function should be like

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $todayDate = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

    $categoryId = $this->getCategoryId();
    $category_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);

    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToSort("entity_id", "DESC")
            ->addCategoryFilter($category_model)
            ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image'))
            ->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInSiteIds())
            ->setOrder($this->get_order(), $this->get_order_dir());
    if (Mage::getStoreConfig('catalogextensions/config4/max_product')) {
        $products->setPageSize(Mage::getStoreConfig('catalogextensions/config4/max_product'));
    }


    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);
    Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($products);

    $this->_productCollection = $products;

    return $this->_productCollection;
}
```

Comment: can i update/replace this method/function into existing list.php method file ?

Comment: yeah, you are right ! now i updated home/list.php code,

Comment: ok now replace your function _getProductCollection()
 with mine. but make sure in every place you put the category_id="2276"

Comment: Still i put the cateogry_id="256" different but getting same product. which is newly added products.

Comment: ok then you will need to debug this product collection query.

Comment: how can it be display different new products in different store ? any other way to do except this extension !

Comment: This is the only good way in which you can filter it by category, otherwise you will need to disable products for the one store which are assign to others. I mean product1 assign to store1 and then you will need to disable it for store2. Products can be differ by only websites and not by stores.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30242/discussion-between-bishal-neupane-and-akhilesh-patel).